# HTML to PHP form data not submitting

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to pass information from an HTML form to a PHP page. My problem is that the data from the form is not getting submitted. What am I doing wrong ?

HTML FORM

```
<div id="go">
    <form method="get" action="client_authorized.php">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="query" class="input-text" />
            <input type="submit" value="Secure Client Access" class="input-submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

client_authorized.php

```
<?php
     print $_GET['query'];
?>
```

Comment: Why have you put your submit button inside another form? When you submit it from that form, you lose data set in other forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div id="go">
    <!-- see the moved `target` attribute from other form element to here -->
    <form target="_blank" method="get" action="client_authorized.php">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="text" name="query" class="input-text" />
            <!-- <form target="_blank"> -->
            <input type="submit" value="Secure Client Access" class="input-submit" />
            <!-- </form> -->
            <!-- this form here is as useless as these comments are, define target in main form -->
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Basicly your second `<form/>` overrides first `<form/>` elements, therefore loses data when posted.

Oh, by the way PHP's `print();` won't print out your array data (at least I think so..), you should use `print_r();` or `var_dump();` instead.

Comment: Tom did as you said. It works thanks...human error is always redundant :)

Comment: My guess would be that @Michael's solution didn't work because of the lost `target` attribute on `<form/>` element. Altho', not 100% sure. It could be possible that when passing elements through $_GET not $_POST, data is lost when posted outside PHP_SELF - blank window.

Answer (score 5):

Your submit button is wrapped in another `<form>`.  This should be an `<input type='submit'>` instead. Just remove the extra `<form></form>`.

```
<div id="go">
  <form method="get" action="client_authorized.php">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="query" class="input-text" />
        <input type="submit" value="Secure Client Access" class="input-submit" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Michael...I tried it it still didn't work. Am I making an error elsewhere ?

Comment: @Vinoth You are certain PHP is functioning properly otherwise?  Do you get anything if you `print_r($_GET);` to dump the contents of the GET vars?